# How to get cgroup path of task in an eBPF program?

Tags: linux-kernel, cgroups, ebpf, bcc-bpf

I have been trying to play with [tcptop](https://github.com/iovisor/bcc/blob/master/tools/tcptop.py) BCC tool by Brendan Gregg to learn more about how eBPF programs work. I am trying to get it to print the CGROUP path of the tasks.

With my rusty knowledge of Linux systems programming, I thought I could use functions from `linux/cgroup.h`, especially `task_cgroup_path()` [looked promising](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v4.19.59/source/include/linux/cgroup.h#L112) as I can pass current `task_struct *` (obtained from `bpf_get_current_task()`) to it. I am using a CentOS7 machine with `4.19.59` kernel.

However, when I try to executed modified tcptop, the verifier fails with `last insn is not an exit or jmp` error message. I am trying to understand why this is happening.

Here's the diff of modified `tcptop`: [patch](https://gist.github.com/soumyadipdm/c0d5610595b9946c71490aaa2d66f350)

Here's the verifier [output](https://gist.github.com/soumyadipdm/736497c2fac752061f93d92c50ef136b)

Comment: Was tcptop working on your system in the first place, before you patched it?

Comment: If the unpatched tcptop was working, did you try introducing your changes one by one to see which one the verifier is complaining about?

Comment: @Qeole yes, BCC tools work just fine.

@pchaigno yes, If I remove call to `task_cgroup_path()`, it works just fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I thought I could use functions from `linux/cgroup.h`

No, you cannot.

The only functions that may be called from an eBPF program are:

- Other functions defined in your eBPF code (they can be inlined but this is no longer necessary, eBPF supports function calls),
- eBPF helpers, which are kernel functions specifically exposed to eBPF programs (see [their documentation in the source](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/include/uapi/linux/bpf.h?h=v5.7#n594) or [as a man page](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/bpf-helpers.7.html)),
- Compiler built-ins, such as `__builtin_memcpy()` for example.

Other kernel functions, even if the symbols are exported and exposed to kernel modules, or user functions from the standard library for that matter, are not callable from an eBPF program (they would be *traceable* with eBPF, but this is different).

Regarding your use case, I am not sure what the best way to get the cgroup path from its id is. You could do it in user space, although I don't know how to get a path from the id. I know the reverse is possible (getting the id from the path, this [can be done](https://github.com/iovisor/bcc/blob/b2aa29fa3269ec54b2c4d95a55559deb4c32b7b6/examples/cgroupid/cgroupid.c) with the `name_to_handle_at()` syscall), so worst case you could iterate on all existing paths and get the ids. If you have a strong use case and some time ahead, a longer-term solution would be to submit a new eBPF helper that would call into `task_cgroup_path()`.

**[Edit]** Regarding the error message returned by the verifier (`last insn is not an exit or jmp`): BPF programs support function calls, so you can have several functions (“subprograms”) in your program. Each of those subprograms is a list of instructions, possibly containing forward or backward (under certain conditions) jumps. From the verifier's point of view, the execution of the program *must* end with an `exit` or unconditional backward jump instruction (a “return” from the subprogram), this is `to avoid fall-through from one subprog into another`. It wouldn't make sense to do nothing specific (return or exit from whole program) at the end of a function, and it would be dangerous (once JIT-ed, programs are not necessarily contiguous in memory so you couldn't fall through safely, even if that made sense).

Now if we look at how clang compiled your program, we see this for the call to `task_cgroup_path()`:

```
; task_cgroup_path(t, (char *) &cgpath, sizeof(cgpath)); // Line  50
  20:   bf 01 00 00 00 00 00 00     r1 = r0
  21:   b7 03 00 00 10 00 00 00     r3 = 16
  22:   85 10 00 00 ff ff ff ff     call -1
```

The `call -1` is a call to a BPF function (not a kernel helper, but a function expected to be found in your program, you can tell with the source register being set at 1 (`BPF_PSEUDO_CALL`) on the second byte of the instruction). So the verifier considers that the target for this jump is a subprogram. Except that because `task_cgroup_path()` is not a BPF subprogram, clang could not find it to set a relevant offset and used `-1` instead, marking the `call -1` as the first instruction of this would-be subprogram. But the last instruction before the `call -1` is neither an `exit` nor a `jump`, so the verifier eventually catches that something is wrong with the program, and rejects it. All this logic happens in function [`check_subprogs()`](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/kernel/bpf/verifier.c?h=v5.7#n1372).

Comment: Thanks for the directions. I am also interested in knowing why verifier is throwing `last insn is not an exit or jmp`. From https://github.com/torvalds/linux/commit/cc8b0b92a1699bc32f7fec71daa2bfc90de43a4d as per the comment, `the last insn of the subprog should be either exit or unconditional jump back`. I am trying to understand what that means.

Comment: Thank you so much for the detailed explanation!

Answer (score 0):

below codes show how to get containerid:

```
static __always_inline int get_cgroup_name(char *buf, size_t sz) {
    struct task_struct *cur_tsk = (struct task_struct *)bpf_get_current_task();
    if (cur_tsk == NULL) {
        bpf_printk("failed to get cur task\n");
        return -1;
    }

    int cgrp_id = memory_cgrp_id;


    // failed when use BPF_PROBE_READ
    const char *name = BPF_CORE_READ(cur_tsk, cgroups, subsys[cgrp_id], cgroup, kn, name);
    bpf_printk("name: %s\n", name);
    if (bpf_probe_read_kernel_str(buf, sz, name) < 0) {
        bpf_printk("failed to get kernfs node name: %s\n", buf);
        return -1;
    }
    bpf_printk("cgroup name: %s\n", buf);

    return 0;
}
```

if you want to get cgroupid, maybe should access `task_struct->cgroups->subsys[cgrp_id]->cgroup->kn->id`.

Then use `find /sys/fs/cgroup -inum {id}` will get cgroup path